# Not seeing lower level shader syntax errors

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl

I'm using Next.js with Three.js and now when I encounter shader errors, I only see a warning in Chrome with `WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid`. I remember before when I was using regular React with Three.js, I saw more detailed program info saying the line the syntax error occurs in the shader.

Is there something I need to enable to get that level of debugging back?

Comment: you can try using [webgl-lint](https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest fix for this was to set `renderer.debug.checkShaderErrors = true`